# Perfect set without rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Give an example of a perfect set in $\mathbb R^n$ that does not contain any of the rationals.

(Or prove that it does not exist).

Comment: Hint: It exists, and you can even construct such a set of specified Lebesgue measure.

Comment: What is a perfect set? Also, this looks like a homework problem.

Comment: Why are you asking if you apparently know the answer?

Comment: @Kevin: Line Bundle is not asking homework questions - no-one would have homework on so many different areas at once

Comment: @Kevin, a perfect set is one which is equal to its derived set, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set

Comment: Mariano has started a discussion at meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/313/asking-questions-whose-answers-are-clearly-known-to-the-op

Comment: @Casebash: It may not be a homework question assigned to the asker, but I agree that it looks like one.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/381690/462 If $C$ is the standard Cantor set, then for comeager many $x$, we have that $C+x$ consists only of irrationals.

Comment: For context, this is Baby Rudin Exercise 2.18. It is quite a bit harder than most other problems in the book. It is not clear what Rudin had in mind, since the Cantor set translation argument uses the Baire Category Theorem in the form of the later Exercise 2.30. Possibly Rudin intended something like JDH's argument since Exercise 2.17 deals with decimal expansions with only digits 4 and 7.

Answer (score 50):

An easy example comes from the fact that a number with an infinite [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expansion is irrational (and conversely). The set of all irrationals with continued fractions consisting only of 1's and 2's in any arrangement is a perfect set of irrational numbers.

Comment: This is a really nice answer!

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Answer (score 33):

Consider the set of reals x whose binary expansion, if you look only at the even digit places, is some fixed non-eventually-repeating pattern z. This is perfect, since we have branching at the odd digits, but they are all irrational, since z is not eventually repeating.

You can draw a picture of this set, and it looks something like the Cantor middle third set, except that you divide into four pieces, and take either first+third or second+fourth, depending on the digits of z.

Another solution: Begin with an interval having irrational endpoints, and perform the usual Cantor middle-third construction, except that at stage n, be sure to exclude the n-th rational number (with respect to some fixed enumeration), using a subinterval having irrational endpoints. By systematically excluding all rational numbers, you have the desired perfect set of irrationals.

(Hi François!)

Comment: Hi Joel! Nice answer!

Comment: I was answering this in baby Rudin 2.18, with an approach similar to the first approach of yours, and found it easier to construct explicit bounds on neighborhoods especially when proving that the set is closed if we instead consider decimal expansion and limit ourselves to numbers in [0,1] with digits in 4 and 7 , since we obviate the need to reason about carries in the decimal representation for sufficiently small neighborhoods. Note that the previous exercise in baby Rudin already has you prove some properties about the set of numbers in [0,1] with digits in 4 and 7.

Answer (score 27):

It is well-known that $C$ is homeomorphic to $C \times C$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, as both are zero-dimensional compact metric spaces without isolated points. So $C$ contains uncountably many disjoint homeomorphic copies of $C$ and at most countably many of them can contain rationals...

Comment: This is now my favorite example of a nonconstructive proof.

Comment: @Bryan Thx. It shows the power of the characterisation theorem nicely, I think. It's a folklore argument, don't know whose it is originally.

Answer (score 13):

Just consider a translation of Cantor set $C$, denote as $E=C+\{x_0\}$. The perfectness of $E$ is trivial due to the perfectness of $C$. To make $E\cap\mathbb{Q}=\varnothing$, we need to choose an $x_0\notin \mathbb{Q}-C$. The only thing left is to show $\mathbb{Q}-C\neq\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}+C\neq\mathbb{R}$. By Baire Category theorem
$$\mathbb{Q}+C=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}\{r\}+C$$
can't have any interior point, since $\{r\}+C$ don't have any interior point, for any $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. The conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be an open subset of $R$ of finite measure and containing $Q$. This is possible because $Q$ is countable. Let $B=R$ \ $A$. Now $B$ is closed, and uncountable (because it has infinite measure). Let $ C$ be the family of open real intervals that, each, have countable intersection with $B$. Then $\cup C$ is equal to $\cup D$ where $ D $ is a countable subset of $ C$, so $B$ has countable intersection with $\cup C$. The uncountable closed set $E= B$ \ $\cup C$ is perfect. Indeed, if $p \in E$ and $V$ is an open interval containing $p$, then $E \cap V$ is uncountable.