# Question about irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

How  to show :

> If $A \subseteq \mathbb{I}$ is not
>   countable, then $A$ is not closed set
>   in $\mathbb{R}$.

I think that if $A$ is closed, then $A^{c}$ is open thus: $A^{c}$ is an union of open intervals, but...

Comment: @Bryan Yocks: Most of those tags are inappropriate; this is not calculus, not set-theory, not analysis,...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is $\mathbb I$?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{I}$? If you mean $\mathbb{I}$ to be an open interval, your statement is not true. For instance take $\mathbb{I} = (0,1)$ and let $A \subset \mathbb{I}$ be $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}]$. Clearly, $A$ is not countable and is a closed set. Are you missing something or am I missing something?

Comment: Rasmus, the irrational numbers

Comment: Is $\mathbb I$ the irrational numbers? If that's so, your statement seems true, but what is your question?

Comment: Btw, $\mathbb I$ is not a commonly used symbol for the irrationals. $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ are almost universally accepted to represent the reals and the rationals, so $\mathbb{ R \backslash Q }$ would be a much clearer way to represent the irrationals to a general audience.

Comment: I tend to use $\mathbb{I}$ for the irrationals as well Bryan; however, it is probably best to define what you mean by your notations when you are using them in general and people may not understand them.

I just wanted to let you know that I do not think it is wrong to use a less common symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is not true.  There exist perfect<sup>1</sup> (hence closed) subsets of $\mathbb R$ that doesn't intersect $\mathbb Q$, and [perfect sets are not countable](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html).  See: [Perfect set without rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/perfect-set-without-rationals).

---

<sup>1</sup>  A set $S$ is perfect if it is closed and every point of $S$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

Answer (score 4):

As another counterexample, enumerate the rationals as $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$, and let $U = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (q_k - 2^{-(k+2)}, q_k + 2^{-(k+2)})$.  $U$ is open and contains all the rationals, so its complement $U^c$ is closed and contains none of them.  But $U$ is a union of intervals of lengths $2^{-(k+1)}$, so its Lebesgue measure (i.e. length) is at most $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-(k+1)} = 1/2$.  So $U^c$ has measure at least $1/2$ and in particular must be uncountable.  You can modify this construction to make the  measure of $U^c$ as close to $1$ as desired.

Answer (score 2):

As AgCl pointed out (and François G. Dorais, in the answer AgCl linked to), the statement is false. (And Nate also pointed out, as I was writing my answer.)

I would even say that the point is that ${\mathbb R}\setminus{\mathbb Q}$ is *homeomorphic* to the set ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ (with the product topology of discrete ${\mathbb N}$).

But, obviously, ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ contains lots of perfect subsets, such as $\{1,2\}^{\mathbb N}$.

[A really pretty example of such a homeomorphism in the first chapter of the book "Descriptive Set Theory and Forcing: how to prove theorems about Borel sets the hard way" by Arnold Miller (which you can download from his webpage). The usual construction (which is also pretty) is to note that a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ can be identified with the continued fraction of an irrational in $(0,1)$, and a bit of thought shows that this map is indeed a homeomorphism.]