# Questions about open sets in ${\mathbb R}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following problem:

Let ${\mathbb Q} \subset A\subset {\mathbb R}$, which of the following must be true?

A. If $A$ is open, then $A={\mathbb R}$

B. If $A$ is closed, then $A={\mathbb R}$

Since $\overline{\mathbb Q}={\mathbb R}$, one can immediately get that B is the answer.

Here are my questions:

> Why A is not necessarily true? What can be a counterexample?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A slightly more interesting example than Luboš's can be obtained by enumerating the rationals as $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and taking $A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (q_{n} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}, q_{n} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}})$. Then the Lebesgue measure of $A$ can be estimated by $\mu(A) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}} = \varepsilon$, so $A$ cannot be all of $\mathbb{R}$ even if it's clearly open.

Comment: It's amazing that without knowing what the irrational numbers are left, one can get that $A$ cannot be ${\bf R}$ through Lebesgue measure. Nice!

Comment: @Jack: Of course, I used the [deceptively innocent-looking fact](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51531/theorems-that-are-obvious-but-hard-to-prove/51555#51555) that the Lebesgue measure of an interval is its length! The comments to Gowers's answer show that even some professional mathematicians are not aware of its non-triviality (or forgot about it)...

Comment: This is a very nice classical example. +1, I liked it so much when I saw it the first time :) it's like saying you can "cover" a dense subset of an infinitely long line with a simple woodstick (of finite length), if you "cut it correctly" and "place the pieces at the right places". It shows how mathematics can rudely destroy intuition. =P

Comment: @Patrick: Right. I find it even better when you write $A_{\varepsilon}$ for the set in this answer and take $N = [0,1] \cap \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{1/k}$. Then you get a dense $G_{\delta}$ (hence a set of second Baire category) in $[0,1]$. This set is generic in the sense of Baire, but it has zero Lebesgue measure. In other words: the two notions of *generic* that are commonly used (one in the sense of Baire, the other in the sense of probability) are quite incompatible.

Comment: To be honest, I wiki'ed "second Baire category" to notice that this was a completely non-trivial example, but the generic part related to probability, you lost me. =) It'd be cool if you had something I could look up just to get an idea, but I see your point anyway. =P

Comment: @Patrick: Oh, sorry. The set $N$ has measure zero, right? So if you pick a point randomly (wrt Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$), it won't be in $N$ almost surely, so a "generic point will be outside $N$". On the other hand, this set is a countable intersection of open and dense sets, and according to the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), such sets are "large" or "generic" (in the sense of Baire). E.g.: a generic continuous function is nowhere differentiable. Now $N$ is "very small" in the Lebesgue sense, and "very large" in the Baire sense. That's it.

Comment: Nice explanation. It's good to know

Answer (score 8):

A counterexample for the rule A is 
$$ {\mathbb R} \backslash F $$
where $F$ is any non-empty finite (or countable) set of irrational numbers. For example
$$ {\mathbb R} \backslash \{\pi\} $$
Note that if I remove the point $\pi$, the set is still open on both sides from $\pi$. Because $\pi$ isn't rational, the set above still contains all rational numbers.

Comment: You couldn't remove *any* countable set - for example, removing $\{\frac{\pi}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ would leave you with a set that's not open.

Comment: "(or countable)" could be replaced with "(or closed)" to make this correct and general.

Answer (score 5):

The question boils down to whether there are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ that are closed in $\mathbb{R}$.  The easiest examples are finite sets, as [Luboš Motl noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43640/open-set-in-bf-r/43642#43642).  An easy infinite example is $\sqrt{2}+\mathbb{Z}$.  [Theo Buehler showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43640/open-set-in-bf-r/43643#43643) that there are positive measure examples, which is much stronger and closely related to the question at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21094/is-there-a-compact-subset-of-the-irrationals-with-positive-lebesgue-measure/).

Another direction to strengthen the result is to show that there are perfect examples, which is the subject of the question at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/perfect-set-without-rationals).

Comment: Nice wrap-up, Jonas, and prods to make connections with earlier questions/answers.  A post such as this would be helpful for some answers that get a half-dozen (or more) answers which take a different angle, approach...and to help shed light on how strong (or generalizable/extendable) a statement one can make, "spring-boarding" off a single question, and connecting to other semi-related posts.

Answer (score 0):

"Why A is not necessarily true? What can be a counterexample?"

I'm surprised at the complexity of some answers given to this.  Here's a counterexample:
$$
(-\infty,\pi)\cup (\pi,\infty).
$$
You can construct lots of others similar to that but more complicated if need be.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{\pi\}$ more complicated than your example?

Comment: I.e. the complement of any _discrete_ set of irrational numbers.

Comment: Sorry..... I hadn't thorougly read all of them.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: $\{\frac{\pi}{n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a discrete set of irrationals, but its complement is not open.  The set of irrational numbers in question has to be closed.