# Does every Lebesgue measurable set have the Baire property?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Title says it all, so I'll just repeat it:
Does every Lebesgue measurable set have the Baire property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  (assuming choice, so that there are some sets without the Baire property).

Some hints: Any set with the property of Baire which is not meager, has a subset that fails the property of Baire.  Next, find a Lebesgue null set, with the property of Baire, but not meager.

Comment: Care to give an additional hint on the latter (i.e. Lebesgue null but not meager)? I can find non-meager sets with arbitrarily small Lebesgue measure, but not with measure = 0.

Comment: @Anonymous: You probably know how to produce an open set $U_n$ containing the rationals having measure $\lambda(U_n) \leq 1/n$. Intersect. Get a dense $G_\delta$ of zero measure. See e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43640/questions-about-open-sets-in-mathbb-r/43643#comment-123554) (look at the comments).

Comment: @Theo: I must be very 'dense' today, but I still don't get it: Q is also a dense G_delta set of zero measure. But it's not exactly non-meager, is it?

Comment: @Anonymous: Wait a minute. Yes, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense, it is a meager $F_{\sigma}$ but [it is *not* a $G_\delta$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26311/)!

Comment: @Theo: Ah! Thanks. That's what I've been missing all the time. The intersection isn't Q itself at all, but some larger set. And it's pretty easy to see that it's non-meager, too. Thanks folks!

Answer (score 4):

Just to make the solution from the comments to GEdgar's answer more explicit: The set of real numbers can be partitioned as $\mathbb R = M \cup N$, where $M$ is meager and $N$ is Lebesgue null.  ($N$ is the dense $G_\delta$ described by t.b. above.)

Now every subset of $N$ is Lebesgue measurable, but (using AC) one can find a subset without the Baire property.

Comment: It's consistent that all sets have the Baire property but not all sets are measurable, though. So one has to use the axiom of choice here.