# Are there more real numbers than irrational numbers?

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, infinite-groups

Wrapping my head around the mathematical definition of infinity and just curious here: Are there more real numbers than irrational numbers? It would intuitively seem so, but they are both just uncountable infinite sets, right? Some I guess there would be the same number of irrational numbers as real numbers? But I can't imagine a "bijection" between them. (A term I just learned about five minutes ago...)

Comment: The set of all irrational numbers is a subset of all real numbers. So the set of real numbers has all irrational numbers plus some other numbers (i.e. 1, 0.25, etc).  But if you are talking about cardinality, both sets have the same.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. It seems to be asking for an *example* of a bijection between $\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$, not why $|\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q| > |\mathbb Q|$

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695470/cardinality-of-irrational-numbers) is an answer that gives a bijection between $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. I'm not comparing rational numbers to irrational numbers, I'm comparing irrational numbers to all of the real numbers. The set of real numbers contain the irrational numbers, but both are uncountable infinite sets. So my question is, does that mean that those infinities are equal?